# Spark scala what's the difference between predicate pushdown and partitioning in term of processing and stroge

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using dataframe and I have come across these terms. I couldn't fully understand them if possible, can you give an example on both?

Answer (score 0):

Predicate pushdown is when filtering query results, a consumer of the parquet-mr API in spark can fetch all records from the API and then evaluate each record against the predicates of the filtering condition. Like you are joining two large parquet table -

```
SELECT * FROM museum m JOIN painting p ON p.museumid = m.id WHERE p.width > 120 AND p.height > 150
```

However, this requires assembling all records in memory, even non-matching ones. With predicate pushdown, these conditions are passed to the parquet-mr library instead, which evaluates the predicates on a lower level and discards non-matching records without assembling them first. So data gets filtered first based on the condition then comes to memory to join operations

Partitioning in Spark is actually logically divided data. When you read a file from the s3/ADLS/gzip file of HDFS it creates single partition for each file. Later when you process your data based on Shuffle partition your data frame partition changes accordingly. So I think partitioning and predicate pushdown have only one common factor when to fetch data from columnar files if the filter is applied the data comes to each partition in Spark is lesser than the existing data lying on the file system
Hope this helps

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. This is what I understood when I filter a column before the join, then this is predicate pushdown. And the predicate in this case is the filter. I'm using dataframe and I'm not doing any shuffling partion

Comment: When you run your query it reads your source data from the disk and filters the data while reading not while doing the join. When you read a data frame from the source it does not run immediately, unless you declare an action. When you declare an action it creates a Physical Plan and logical plan. The logical plan defines the fact that you have a source side push down.  It is very similar to the source side push down in any of ETL tools. spark-JDBC is also related source side push down feature

Comment: review.filter("stars > 4"), is this filter pushdown?

Comment: That sets up a filter. Whether it can push that down is a much more complicated and context specific question. If you're not sure if it's pushed down, you can print out the execution plan.

Comment: review.filter("stars > 4"); business.join(review,business("business_id") === review("business_id"),"inner"), I think the filter is pushed down based on the result, if so, can I consider it a filter pushdown

Comment: Adding the filter while reading the dataframe is the predicate pushdown.

Comment: Ok, so how can benefit from partitioning: review.filter("stars > 4"); business.join(review,business("business_id") === review("business_id"),"inner")

Comment: Say your data is distributed to multiple files and while reading it filters >4. So while performing a shuffle hash join Spark gets benefits from each partition level join as they know join key ranges while reading. The data needs to be columnar for that instance

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't follow ur train of throughs. The filter is supposed to help focus on the exact file rather than multiple. But in dataframe there's no shuffle for join, it's in RDD, right

Comment: Try to read some articles on Predicate Pushdown in Parquet and Spark. That would be helpful